# Using HSpec with Stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, hspec

I have the following architecture :

```
  backend
  ├── Chat.hs
  ├── Main.hs
  └── Message.hs
  test
  ├── backendSpec
  │   └── MessageSpec.hs
  └── Spec.hs
```

---

My .cabal file contains the following

```
test-suite spec
  build-depends:  base, hspec == 2.*,
                  snap >= 0.14.0.6,
                  containers,
                  aeson,
                  text,
                  transformers,
                  stm,
                  snap-core,
                  snap-server,
                  socket-io,
                  engine-io-snap,
                  snap-cors,
                  bytestring
  hs-source-dirs: test
  main-is: Spec.hs
  Type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
```

but when I do

```
stack test
```

HSpec cannot find my test int MessageSpec.hs.

> Finished in 0.0002 seconds
>   0 examples, 0 failures

Spec.hs is the correct input : {-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover #-}

and my MessageSpec module is exposing : module MessageSpec (main, spec).

Could you help me find a way to make my stack project doing all my tests.

Thank you,

Comment: Run the command with `-v3` or whatever the equivalent for stack is, so you can see what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path to your spec **must** follow the module name convention. `backendSpec.MessageSpec` is not a valid module name, since it starts with a lowercase letter.

Furthermore, the module name of your spec should only differ by the additional suffix `Spec` from your original module. Your modules in `backendSpec` wouldn't follow this:

```
module Message where ...
-- vs
module BackendSpec.MessageSpec where ...
```

So to fix this, make sure that all directories in your `test` directory start with an uppercase letter. But even better, make sure that the test directory has *the same* structure as your `src` directory, as this will result in better module names during your tests:

```
-- If file is test/BackendSpec/MessageSpec.hs
BackendSpec.Message:
   <someDescription>
      <some assertion>
      <some assertion>
      <some assertion>
```

vs

```
-- If file is test/MessageSpec.hs
Message:
   <someDescription>
      <some assertion>
      <some assertion>
      <some assertion>
```

(The relevant code for this behaviour can be found in [`hspec/Run.hs`](https://github.com/hspec/hspec/blob/master/hspec-discover/src/Test/Hspec/Discover/Run.hs#L120-L139) of `hspec-discover`)